# Convert JSON to XML 'x' elements in array

Tags: arrays, json, node.js, xml

I have a JSON array, which can contain several different elements in it - the number is unknown to me.

JSON:

```
[{
    "_id": "5911a43e6aa5d609d32c590a",
    "criteria": "3",
    "name": "test1"
}, {
    "_id": "5911a43e6aa5d609d32c590d",
    "criteria": "7",
    "name": "test2"
}, {
    "_id": "5911a43e6aa5d609d32c5910",
    "criteria": "2",
    "name": "test3"
}]
```

I need to convert this data into XML, so that it is in the following structure:

```
<MyDefs criteria="3">
    <name>test1</name>
</MyDefs>
<MyDefs criteria="7">
    <name>test3</name>
</MyDefs>
<MyDefs criteria="2">
    <name>test2</name>
</MyDefs>
```

I tried using `xml2js` node library-  I assume I need a foreach loop but not sure how to implement - is there a way to achieve this?

Thank you

Comment: Show the code you currently have and that includes the bit you are struggling with.

Comment: I didnt get anywhere sadly, hence asking for ideas

Comment: Given the fact that you are probably not the first person to ever want to convert a JS object tree to XML I'd say there ought to be quite a few examples to choose from, entire node libraries even. It can't be that you have *nothing*.

Comment: But I havent found a specific example related to the problem I have